# Rolling a die until all of sums exceed 5, what is the most likely value (not expected) to end the game?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've found that {6,7,8,9,10,11} are ends the game but I couldn't find which distribution should I use, maybe cdf?

Comment: Hint: work recursively from states (the states being labelled by the current sum).  If the sum is $5$, what's the answer?  What if the current sum is $4$?

Comment: @lulu I don't know what the state is?

Comment: The state is any number from $0$ to $11$.  For instance, if you are in state $6$, the expected total is obviously $6$, since the game has stopped.  If you are in state $5$ then you will definitely end on the next turn, so the expected total is....

Comment: @lulu is it 8.5?

Comment: If the sum at one point is $5$, there's equal positive chance to end the game in the next turn with sum in $\{6,7,8,9,10,11\}$. If the sum at one point is $4$, there's equal positive chance to end the game in the next turn with sum in $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$. ... If the sum at one point is $0$, there's positive chance to end the game in the next turn with sum in $\{6\}$. So which final sum is more likely?

Comment: @peterwhy then you say 6 is twice likely right?

Comment: Yes, 8.5 is correct for state 5. Now do state 4 and so on.

Comment: While I can't tell the probabilities of each final sum without further calculations, I can tell that for every path to $11$, there is a corresponding path to $10$ with the same intermediate sums and probability, but there are more paths that would end at $10$ but not $11$. So ending at $10$ is more likely than at $11$, and by a similar reason ending at $6$ is even more likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to have the game end on an 11 is for the cumulaive sum to get to 5 followed by the roll of a 6.

If we let $x$ be the penultimate state of the game (that is the state before the final roll) and $Pn(x)$ the probability that $x$ is this penultimate state.  And $y$ is the final state of the game, and $P(y)$ is the probability that the final state is $y.$

$x\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$

$P(11) = P_n(5)\cdot \frac16$ formalised what we had in the first paragraph

For $y = 10$ then we need to have x = 4 and the final roll be a 6, or x = 5 and the final roll is a 5.

$P(10) = P_n(4)\cdot \frac 16 + P_n(5)\cdot \frac 16 = \frac 16(P_n(4) + P_n(5))$

But what about $P(6)?$  We can get to $y=6$ from every value of $x$

$P(6) =  \frac 16 (P_n(0)+P_n(1)+P_n(2)+P_n(3)+P_n(4)+P_n(5))$

And this is the only value of $y$ that can be reached from every possible value of $x$ thus must be the most likely occurence.  We do not need to actually calculate the other probabilities to know that this is true.

Comment: Your conclusion is right, but $P(6) \not= \frac16$ (unless I misunderstand what $P(\cdot)$ represents, which is certainly possible).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness:

This sort of problem can best be handled recursively.  For $i\in \{6,7,8,9,10,11\}$ let $p_n(i)$ denote the probability that you end in state $i$ given that the current sum is $n$.

You are interested in $\{p_0(1),\cdots, p_0(6)\}$.

Of course, for $n\in \{6,7,8,9,10,11\}$ we have $p_n(i)=\delta_{in}$

Now, given that the current sum is $n$ the next roll can take you to anything from $n+1$ to $n+6$, all with equal probability.  It follows that $$n≤5\implies p_n(i)=\frac {p_{n+1}(i)+p_{n+2}(i)+\cdots +p_{n+6}(i)}6$$

It is easy to implement this recursion and we get $$\{p_0(i)\}_{i=1}^6=\{.360,.194, .166,.133,.096,.051\}$$

Note:  for $i=6$ we can just use [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to do the computation (this won't easily work for the other cases, since for those you need to face the fact that no roll can be $>6$).  There are $\binom {6-1}{k-1}$ paths of length $k$ that get you to $6$ and each of those has probability $\frac 1{6^k}$.  Thus $$p_0(6)=\sum_{k=1}^6 \frac 1{6^k}\times \binom {6-1}{k-1}=.360$$
as before.

Of course, one could use this method to determine the probabilities that you reach $1,2,3,4,5$ and from there it's easy to finish the computation, though for larger end totals you'll still need some recursion.